# PostgreSQL 9.2 update query on a subset

Tags: postgresql, query, update

I wish to make an update using CASE, on a subset of a table. This subset is based on a spatial query.
It looks like:

```
update t1
set f1 = CASE WHEN...
         WHEN...
         END
FROM (select * from t2 join t1 on st_intersects(t2.geom, t1.geom)
WHERE *a_field_from_t2* = *a_value*) as foo ;
```

This update always works with the whole set of t1 i.e. the spatial is not used.

I can't find the reason why. Any help?